# Proper way to report error back in Firebase Functions HTTPS request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I implemented a Firebase function to be called plainly on HTTPS via browser (I use postman for testing) in node.js :

```
exports.notifToAdmin = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const title = request.query.title
  const body = request.query.body
  const badge = request.query.badge
  if (typeof title === 'undefined') { return response.status(500).send("title missing") }
  if (typeof body === 'undefined') { return response.status(500).send("body missing") }
  if (typeof badge === 'undefined') { return response.status(500).send("badge missing") }
  notifications.sendNotifToAdmin(title, body, badge)
    .then(message => {
      const ackString = fingerPrint(msg);
      return response.send(ackString);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      return response.status(500).send(error);
    });
});
```

- am I using a correct way to send errors back to the caller (via the `response.status(500).send("....")`)? In the [Firebase errors documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors) I see the usage of `throw new Error(...)`. So I am unsure if what I do is the most optimal way? I did notice the doc saying `//Will cause a cold start if not caught`(linked to this throw error), I don't want to restart anything just report an error to the caller...
- I know that the onRequest result should be a promise should I change my code and put a `return` in front of the `notifications.SendNotifToAdmin(...)` (this returns a promise) but how does this add up with the `return response.send(...)`? Is this also returning a promise then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> am I using a correct way to send errors back to the caller (via the response.status(500).send("...."))

Yes, that is standard for HTTP type functions that need to send an HTTP status code.  But you should send a 4xx range HTTP codes for errors that are related to the client sending incorrect information.

> I know that the onRequest result should be a promise

There is absolutely no obligation for an onRequest type function to return a promise.  The function just needs to send a response **after** all promises are resolved so that the async work can complete before the function is terminated when the response is delivered.